# Changing status code from 502 to 503 in fallback route

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx as proxy server for my project. In case my app is offline for maintenance I'd like to show a fallback page. This works fine so far. The only problem is, that the server response with a 502 error code - which makes sense. How do I change it to a 503 route in my fallback though?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 @fallback;

   location / {
     proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;
   }

   location @fallback {
       // I need this to answer with a status of 503 instead of a 502
       root /srv/my-project/static;
       try_files /fallback.html;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can set a error page [nginx error page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page)

and set somethig like

`error_page 502 =503 /maintenance.html`

or something like

```
    location / {
        error_page 502 =503 /maintenance.html;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/my.sock;
    }
    location /maintenance.html {
        return 503;
    }
```

source : [How can I make Nginx return HTTP 503 when my proxied app server is down?](https://serverfault.com/questions/186632/how-can-i-make-nginx-return-http-503-when-my-proxied-app-server-is-down)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @shalbafzadeh for that answer, that solved it for me.

In my very particular situation the solution looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    error_page 502 =503 @fallback; <-- THIS

   location / {
     proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;
   }

   location @fallback {
       root /srv/my-project/static;
       try_files /fallback.html;
   }

}
```